# removing text added to a plot with mtext

Tags: r, text, plot

Having added text to an R plot with mtext

e.g.

```
mtext("my added text",side=1)
```

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 8):

Make another plot. (They are dirt cheap after all). `mtext` like most base graphic functions operates via a one-way side-effect model of plotting. There is no underlying storage facility that can be modified after the fact. ( I in the past have tried writing over with identical `col="white"` letters but it looks terrible.)  Failing that, if one is on an OS that has a default "Save as.." that creates a pdf file, then one can use a pdf-editing program.

Comment: had one been using grid graphics, there is a `grid.remove()` function, which i believe simply redraws the rest of the content on the device.