# plot in r - remove and rename titles and labels

Tags: r, plot

I have created the following plot

```
bootresults<-boot.relimp(model3_a_out, b=1000) 
ci<-booteval.relimp(bootresults, norank=T)
plot(ci)
```

[image]

**How can i remove the plots title and subtitle ? also how to remove the annotation of the bottom ?**

i tried `main = NULL` but it does not work.

**also how can i rename the variables ?**

for reporoducible example:

```
> usedata('gpa')
> 
> gpa.model<-lm(c.gpa~h.gpa+SAT+recommd, data=gpa)
> bootresults<-boot.relimp(gpa.model, b=1000) 
> ci<-booteval.relimp(bootresults, norank=T)
> plot(ci)
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

Main title and sub title can remove `plot(x = x, y = y, main = NULL, sub = NULL)`. But i think your plot is made `mtext` function. [mtext example(using plot margin)](http://rgraphics.limnology.wisc.edu/rmargins_sf.php) So they recommend make another plot. [mtext answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101665/removing-text-added-to-a-plot-with-mtext)